# Pyspark: Incremental load, How to overwrite/update Hive table where data is being read

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm currently writing a script for a `daily incremental ETL`. I used a initial load script to load base data to a hive table. Thereafter, I created a daily incremental script and reads from the same table, and uses that same data to run the 2nd script.

Initially, I tried to `"APPEND"` the new data with the daily incremental script, however that seemed to create duplicate rows. So, now I'm attempting to `"OVERWRITE"` the hive table instead, thus creating the below exception.

I noticed others with a similar issue, that want to read and overwrite the same table have tried to `"refreshTable"` before overwriting... I tried this solution as well, but I'm still receiving the same error?

Maybe I should refresh the table path as well?

-Thanks

The Error:

`Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://essnp/sync/dev_42124_edw_b/EDW/SALES_MKTG360/RZ/FS_FLEET_ACCOUNT_LRF/Data/part-00000-4db6432b-f59c-4112-83c2-672140348454-c000.snappy.parquet`

`It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.`

End of my code:

````
###### Loading the LRF table ######

spark.catalog.refreshTable(TABLE_NAME)

hive.write_sdf_as_parquet(spark,final_df_converted,TABLE_NAME,TABLE_PATH,mode='overwrite')

print("LOAD COMPLETED " + str(datetime.now())) 

####### Ending SparkSession #######

spark.sparkContext.stop()

spark.stop() ```
````

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good habit to read and write to same path,

as per spark DAG lineage, some time read and write both happens at the same time, so it's expected.

Better to read from one location and write to another location.